# Select data as JSONB where value used as json key

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

100500 times I found answer here but not now.

I have *PostgreSQL 11.1* and table

```
CREATE TABLE public.bots_script_elements (
    id integer,
    icon text,
    CONSTRAINT bots_script_elements_pri PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Values

```
ID  ICON
1   "begin"
2   "form"
3   "calendar"
```

How can I select data as json below?

```
{
  "1": {"id":1, "icon":"begin"},
  "2": {"id":2, "icon":"form"},
  "3": {"id":3, "icon":"calendar"}
}
```

Json object keys 1, 2 and 3 is value from ID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [jsonb_object_agg()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select jsonb_object_agg(id, to_jsonb(b))
from bots_script_elements b
```

[Test it in rextester.](https://rextester.com/PSR61879)